# Best way to search and replace in Azure DevOps based on release stage

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops

I'm creating a Release pipeline in Azure DevOps which includes a dacpac deployment step. Many of the SQL scripts include a reference to another SQL Server database through a linked server. For various reasons, the database name is different on dev, UAT and production. In our source, it's hard-coded to dev, e.g.:

```
select * from LW.devdb.dbo.Account
```

We change the names with a manual search and replace when we do a UAT deployment

```
select * from LW.uatdb.dbo.Account
```

I'd like to be able to this automatically as part of the UAT stage in Azure DevOps. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is various number of extensions to replace strings in files. For your purpose [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Samayas.azuredevops-samayas-replaceinfiles) should be sufficient to replace database name in SQL scripts.

Answer (score 0):

> Best way to search and replace in Azure DevOps based on release stage

You could use the task [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to update the database name based on the different stages.

As test, change the database name in the `.sql` file:

```
select * from LW.#{DatabaseName}#db.dbo.Account
```

The format of database name in `.sql` file is `#{DatabaseName}#`

Then, set the variables for the variable `DatabaseName` for different stages:

[image]

Add the Replace Tokens to replace the variable in the source file:

[image]

With this task, the variable #{DatabaseName}# in the source file will be replaced by the value of variable `DatabaseName`:

```
select * from LW.devdb.dbo.Account
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This is good info, but doesn't work for us. There are hundreds of place where we would have to put tokens in sql files and it would be unwieldy to try to work with during development.